# DBUnit Android issue

Tags: android, dbunit

I want to implement db testing for android app. When I add dependency to build.grage file `compile 'org.dbunit:dbunit:2.4.3'` I get error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt
    File 1: /root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/761ea405b9b37ced573d2df0d1e3a4e0f9edc668/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
    File 2: /home/user/projects/m1android_studio/app/libs/freemarker.jar
```

When I add dependency  `testCompile 'org.dbunit:dbunit:2.4.3'` project runs normally, but all imported classes from import org.dbunit aren't available.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}
```